# Spinner onItemSelected doesn't work when i use setAdapter()

Tags: android, spinner

I have 1 spinner named spinner1. visiblity set to invisible. then i use an image button to perform click to launch spinner. 
When i give array data from strings.xml. it calls onItemSelected. (static array)
but when i user arrayadapter to setadapter of spinner. it doesnt fire onItemSelected event.

let me show you some code.

```
final Spinner catlist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> spnadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.style1,android.R.id.text1,phone_numbers);

catlist.setAdapter(spnadp);
catlist.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bbname came is ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {        
    }
});
```

and phone_numbers is an ArrayList.

```
ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
           catlist.performClick();
    }
});
```

this is how i call that.

so my question is what is wrong with setting adapter.
if i dont setadapter it works fine . it fire Onitemselected(). and in other case it doesnt.

***Edited:*** (style1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/maroon"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

@Hiral
Application force close and i got this...

```
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1495)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1892)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
09-13 14:55:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,you are not getting it just because of this line of your code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spnadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.style1,android.R.id.text1,phone_numbers);
```

Here your 2nd argument is your layout file..But then,your third argument should be a id of the textview that is in your layout file,you specified in your 2nd argument.mistakenly you added android there before R.id.text1. which will look into android default layout for the id you specified and won't get the one.

So try changing this line as :

(for default layout):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spnadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.id.simple_spinner_item,phone_numbers);
```

and try!

For more reference:

[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5C%5B%5C%5D%29)

**EDIT :**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spnadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.style1,phone_numbers);
```

and make your style1.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/maroon"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
/>
```

Comment: Can you post your edited code to your question under EDIT heading? so that i can look into if you still making a mistake.

Because the problem is not related to your spinner.It seems to be just of Adapter you are specifying and this was one of the mistake there,which i pointed out in my answer.

Comment: you still have the same mistake: remove android.R.layout.text1 and make it R.id.text1 in your adapter definition and try.

Comment: BTW,what did you change in your new edited code? i don't see any difference!

Comment: no no. you took that thing wrong. there no textview in my UI. that text1(textview) belong to style1.xml. if i ll give R.id.text1 it will look for text1 in my same UI(where i have only used a listview and a imagebutton), it gives error. there is no id like text1.

Comment: simply saying it works well if i give static data.. in listview. but when i give dynamic data. it doesn't fire event.

Comment: @Bhupinder: no..it will look for that text1 in your layout style1.xml only.. refer the link i suggested. You should have tried first,with what i suggested. without trying you won't be able to solve your issue.

Comment: i have tried bro. i don't know how to post screenshot(images) here. It gives error "text1 can't be resolved or not a field."

Comment: even i have tried default too. but onItemSelected doenst work

Comment: what time_options?? mean here?

Answer (score 0):

you could not perform  `OnItemSelectedListener` event of `spinner`  in your  `ImageButton`  `OnClickListener` event using `catlist.performClick()` method

Comment: nopes. ankitmakwana . we can perform. its working in my code. when i use array data from strings.xml,it works fine. that is not the problem. i have tested that. if i make setadapter() statement comment. it works fine in above case.

Comment: Let me clear the question:
I have two situations.
What is Common: one spinner1. visiblity invisible. called using imagebutton onclick event.
Different: 1. In first case i filled spinner data with array(source is strings.xml, static data). and its onItemSelected wworks fine.
2. In second case same spinner i fill data using ArrayAdapter(dynamic data) as in code. and i use setAdapter() method. But in this case onItemSelected doesn't work.

Comment: why you using spinner1. visiblity invisible. ? pls explian

Comment: instead of invisible  use Gone

Comment: i don't want to show spinner. spinner will display contents when i press any imagebutton.
i have checked making spinner1 visible, invisible,gone.. none makes difference

Comment: when you click then spinner is gone?

Comment: when i click imagebutton it display spinner with contents(dynamically set by adapter). but when i tap on any item. nothing happens. spinner gone.. i return back to UI

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why and how. its working now. i added a line before setadapter.

```
spnadp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: but not properly working. it only work if i have more than one item in spinner and .. doesn;t work for default selected